# Gap below content on iPad

Tags: html, css, ipad

I've got a webpage set up where I have some links in the middle, and under that a div floated right on the side, about 25% of the screen and another div with `position: fixed, left: 0, bottom: 0`. On my desktop, in Firefox, the image inside the fixed position div sits right in the bottom left corner. However, on the iPad there is a large gap under the floated right div. The image will either start below the view on the screen or even way farther down the page with a massive gap in content between the top of the image and the bottom of the last block of text.

#### HTML:

```
  <div class="wrapper">
     <div id="containerLeft">
        <img id="ipad" src="images/ipad-small.png" alt="a picture of an ipad held in a hand" />
     </div> 

     <div id="containerRight">
        <article>
           <p> stuff </p>
           <p> more stuff </p>
        </article>
     </div>
  </div>
```

#### CSS:

```
    .wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/* ------------ Left Container Content - image ------------- */
#containerLeft{
    width: 50%;
    z-index:-9999; 
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}

#containerLeft img{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: block;
}

/* ---------- Right Container Content - copy on the side ---------------- */
#containerRight{
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
    margin: 50px 3.854167% 0 0;
}

#containerRight article{
    width: 100%;
}

#containerRight article p{
    line-height: 140%;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 0.45em;
    text-align: right;
    font-style: italic;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 2% 0 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell from this what is causing the large gap at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: I tested a few things. I removed all the content from the body, still scrollable on the iPad. I made the background all black, i.e. no images. Still scrollable. It's like there is a minimum height for the iPad yet any time I try to set it in the html tag(max-height: 760px) it does nothing.

Comment: Hi Ethan, welcome to [so].  Does this occur only on the iPad or on any small screen device (e.g. smartphone, netbook, etc.)?  If it isn't an iOS/Safari specific issue, then there's something that you'll need to address.  Anyway, if you're looking to include information about your question, go ahead and edit it - it's better to include it right in your question.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm using the iOS Simulator on the Mac so I can only test on Mobile Safari. Because of your response I popped onto http://ipadpeek.com/ to check it out and discovered there was no scroll... Since I don't have an actual device I can't confirm which I should trust but I'd like to lean more towards the one developed by Apple. Should I not be trusting iOS Simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's based on your screen resolution. Here is the issue:

```
#containerLeft img{
position: fixed;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
display: block;
}
```

The bottom attribute gives you much more whitespace on hi-res screens.

Comment: How can I code this so that the image will sit in the bottom corner of the iPad's screen also then? Position: absolute wasn't working either.

Comment: @Ethan22 I would try to find someone with an Ipad to test it for you. Could be that the simulator was reading the screen size of your computer and translating that to the "ipad" simulator.

Comment: Dang iOS Simulator. Was trying to stay somewhat self sufficient but if it can't be helped... Alright, will do, thanks for the help.